# Has anyone created a ARM template to register a application and create a client secret in Azure AD?

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-active-directory, azure-functions, azure-resource-manager

I tried to automate an application registration and creating a client secret in AD using an ARM template in Azure, but I'm not able to complete this.

Here is the template :

```
{
  "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2019-04-01/deploymentTemplate.json#",
  "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
  "parameters": {
    "appName": {
      "type": "string",
      "metadata": {
        "description": "The name of the application."
      }
    }
  },
  "resources": [
    {
      "type": "Microsoft.AzureAD/applications",
      "apiVersion": "2021-07-01",
      "name": "[parameters('appName')]",
      "location": "westus",
      "properties": {
        "displayName": "[parameters('appName')]",
      }
    },
    {
      "type": "Microsoft.Authorization/roleAssignments",
      "apiVersion": "2020-04-01-preview",
      "name": "[guid(concat('Microsoft.Authorization/roleAssignments/', parameters('appName')))]",
      "properties": {
        "roleDefinitionId": "[concat('/subscriptions/', subscription().subscriptionId, '/providers/Microsoft.Authorization/roleDefinitions/', '1f3afdf9-d0c9-4c3d-847f-89da613e70a8')]",
        "principalId": "[reference(concat('Microsoft.AzureAD/applications/', parameters('appName')), '2021-07-01', 'Full').objectId]",
        "scope": "[subscription().id]"
      }
    }
  ],
  "outputs": {
    "applicationId": {
      "type": "string",
      "value": "[reference(concat('Microsoft.AzureAD/applications/', parameters('appName')), '2021-07-01').appId]"
    },
    "tenantId": {
      "type": "string",
      "value": "[subscription().tenantId]"
    }
  }
}
```

Can anyone help me finish this?

Comment: Not sure where you got the `Microsoft.AzureAD/applications` tpye but AFAIK it is not possible. The MS Graph and ARM APIs are differents. You can create managed identity which are managed service principal but you can't create app registration through ARM. Using terraform you should be able to do it tho

Comment: @Thomas Thanks for the comment. Is it possible to create a managed identity  as mentioned in this https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/templates/deployment-script-template?tabs=CLI#configure-the-minimum-permissions  to provide a access to storage account and container instance via ARM template

Answer (score 2):

It's not possible because the `ARM template` is used to create Azure resources as part of an Azure subscription. However, App Registration is a resource of the `Azure AD` module.

Refer [github](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/issues/51914) for the similar issue discussion.

Instead of trying to run through automation scripts, you can use `Az PowerShell` or `AzCLI` respective commands to register an app and a client secret.

**`New-AzureADApplication`**:

[image]

If still you want to try with Azure ARM templates, the only way to do so is using deployment scripts, which is explained here in detailed. Refer [article](https://moimhossain.com/2020/04/03/azure-ad-app-via-arm-template-deployment-scripts/) by @Moim Hossain.

You need to pass a `CLI/PowerShell` command in the `script content` block under `Microsoft.Resources/deploymentScripts` as follows:

```bash
 "scriptContent":
 "app=$(az ad app create --display-name <testapp>)"
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, this will help me. Is it possible to provide a role access to storage accounts and container instances using ARM template?

Comment: Yes, it is possible to provide a role access to storage accounts and container instances using ARM template. Refer [Doc1](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/blob/main/articles/storage/blobs/storage-auth-abac-cli.md) & [Doc2](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/blob/main/articles/container-apps/azure-resource-manager-api-spec.md). @DAK

Comment: Not able to understand this 
https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/blob/main/articles/azure-resource-manager/templates/deployment-script-template.md#configure-the-minimum-permissions

in this,
is this possible to create user-assigned managed identity  and assign custom roles to that via ARM?

I tried that but failing

Comment: It is possible and can be done using `identity` block as given [here](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/blob/main/articles/container-apps/managed-identity.md).

Comment: Is there any way to create a application by using a terraform template by user authorisation in azure portal?

Comment: Can you explain a bit more clear on your ask? In terraform & portal?

Comment: I tried to register an application and then create a client secret using ARM template and deployment scripts but it's not succeeded. while searching found that terraform has that feature. but i am not sure whether it's possible to execute the terraform template from Azure portal

Comment: You can execute the terraform template through Azure Cloud Shell(bash). @DAK

Comment: Will that works for you? @DAK

Comment: whether that shell execution done by ARM template? and using powershell if yes that can work for me
is there any sample file like that?

Comment: Create a file using `vi <filename>.json` command and then execute deployment with `New-Azsubscriptiondeployment`or `New-AzResourceGroupDeployment ` commands.